# show repeated column value only once

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, ms-access

Here i am working only on a library management project for my course.I have three tables currently

> (books,authors,book_authors)

`books` and `authors` have many to many relationship between them and `book_author` is an intermideate table

here is my book_author table.Here you can see the book which has id=1 is written by two authors.What i am willing to do is whenever i fetch that book i want the book title repeat only once.

[image]

i am using the following query  to fetch book title and author name

```
SELECT  DISTINCT books.title, authors.author_name FROM (books INNER JOIN book_author ON books.ID=book_author.book_id ) INNER JOIN authors ON authors.ID=book_author.author_id WHERE books.ID=1
```

result is the following .Here title is repeated twice which is obvious.But i want to repeat the title only once but two author name to show as well.How i can achieve that ?

[image]

Comment: How do you plan to display this data to your users?

Comment: i want the title will show only once but both authors will show.Otherwise user might think they are two different books from two different authors having similar name

Comment: Issues of data display are best resolved in the presentation layer, if that's available, e.g. a simple loop in PHP (or perhaps ASP or VB)

Comment: Also, note that the ID column on this table serves no purpose.

Comment: Using this SELECT you receive distinct combinations of books and authors. Besides: you will never get data from two rows to appear in one, unless you combine them in a function, usually a UDF.

Comment: One solution may be to create a collection of books, and everytime you add a book to the list, also add it to the collection....then, before you add the book to the list, check to see if it already exists in the collection, and if it does, then do not add it.....This may not work for your situation though, because you are getting distinct combinations for books and authors, and if you follow this method, you would leave some combinations out of your displayed results.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use some User Defined Function (UDF). In Access VBA:

```
Public Function ConcatFields(TblName as String, FieldName as String, Optional Condition As String = "") As String
    Dim rst as Dao.Recorset, StrSQL as String
    StrSQL = "SELECT " & FieldName  & " FROM " & TblName  
    IF Len(Condition) > 0 Then
        StrSQL = StrSQL & " WHERE " & Condition 
    End if
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset (StrSQL )
    Do While Not rst.Eof
        ConcatFields = ConcatFields & rst.Fields(FieldName ) & ", "
    rst.MoveNext: Loop
    IF Right(ConcatFields, Len(", ") = ", ") Then 
         ConcatFields = Left(ConcatFields, Len(ConcatFields) -  Len(", "))
    End If
End Function
```

This Is you SQL:

```
SELECT books.title, ConcatFields('book_author INNER JOIN authors ON authors.ID=book_author.author_id', 'authors.author_name', 'book_author.book_id = ' & books.ID)
FROM books
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Regards,
Andrii

Comment: here i am not using any aggregate function.How i can use group by here

Comment: By adding `MIN` or `GROUP_CONCAT` on `author_name`

Comment: Use a comment if you just wish to throw a hint.